# How to mount component only when i change class props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ReactJS project where i get JSON from REST Django host and creating a table with filters for it. I have a Table class :

```
class MainTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(this.props.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table hover striped bordered responsive size="sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.results.map(result =>
            <tr key={result.fileId}>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
              <td>{result.Name}</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

And Main where i run all filter classes :

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      origin: '',
      limit: 10
    };

    this.handleChangeOrigin = this.handleChangeOrigin.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeLimit = this.handleChangeLimit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangeLimit(event) {
    this.setState({limit: event.target.value});
  }
  handleChangeOrigin(event) {
    this.setState({origin: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    var link = `http://106.120.89.142:8000/database/?limit=${this.state.limit}&`;
    if (this.state.origin){
      link += `ORIGIN=${this.state.origin.toLowerCase()}`;
      console.log(link)
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="jumbotron-heading display-4">Here u got database *_*</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Limit handleChange = {this.handleChangeLimit} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <OriginRow handleChange = {this.handleChangeOrigin} />
        </div>
        <div id="tableWrapper">
          <MainTable link={link} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And i have a problem with it, cause when i use `componentDidMount()`, my `axios.get(my link to REST JSON)` runs only once. When i use `axios` in `Table class render()`, it hits my server few times per second. Can i make mounting only when my props to Table class changed?

Comment: *"Can i make mounting only when my props to Table class changed?"* - do you mean the `TableMain` component? Because `Table` is a react-bootsrap component.

Comment: `MainTable class`, exactly. Sorry, I could be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) life-cycle method, [**here**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

> **shouldComponentUpdate()**
>
> ```
> shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to let React know if a component's output is not affected by the current change in state or props. The default behavior is to re-render on every state change, and in the vast majority of cases you should rely on the default behavior.
>
> `shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received. Defaults to `true`. This method is not called for the initial render or when `forceUpdate()` is used.

---

Add the following snippet to your `MainTable` component. This will prevent it from re-rendering, unless the `props` have changed.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps);
}
```

this will check for **all** props. If you want to check against a **specific** prop, you can do:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return JSON.stringify(this.props.link) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.link);
}
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, there is always a *small* chance that `JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps)` will return `false` even when they are equal.

As such, if you want a more robust way of comparing the `this.props` object to the `newProps` object, you should take a look at [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not stable in the order of the keys, so this introduces a bug. At least a bug which, in this case, will usually result in a re-render where it wouldn't have been wanted.

Comment: Thank u so much, but one more question. How to run my `MainTable` on start, I got an ampty `Table` before filtering now, and i want to get all the database there as before.

Comment: Objects in JavaScript aren't ordered and stringify doesn't order them either, so you're just relying on undefined behavior. See  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out you can implement shouldComponentUpdate.  Alternatively if you dont need a deep comparison, ie on any collections or objects, just use PureComponent instead of Component:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/docs/docs/reference-react.md

React.PureComponent#
React.PureComponent is exactly like React.Component but implements shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow prop and state comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for help, the best solution I found and choose is :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(this.props.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results, count: res.data.count});
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    axios.get(nextProps.link)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({results: res.data.results, count: res.data.count});
    });
  }
```

It's exactly what I need, you can read about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops. It rerun my `render()` every time I get new `props` and I didn't use `axios` in my `render`, which is more attractive.